# Output of gcloud list commands not displaying in table form

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm using the `gcloud` command in Google Cloud Shell. A tutorial I'm following, as well as the documentation (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/zones/list), says that to list all the zones in table form you should use this command:

```
gcloud compute zones list
```

When I run it the results are listed not in a table, but like this:

```
NAME: us-west2-b
REGION: us-west2
STATUS: UP
NEXT_MAINTENANCE:
TURNDOWN_DATE:

NAME: us-west2-c
REGION: us-west2
STATUS: UP
NEXT_MAINTENANCE:
TURNDOWN_DATE:

NAME: us-west3-a
REGION: us-west3
STATUS: UP
NEXT_MAINTENANCE:
TURNDOWN_DATE:
```

This is a brand new pristine Google Cloud account. Did Google change the default output formatting for the `list` commands?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found that if I set `accessibility/screen_reader` to `false` then the output is listed in table form:

```
gcloud config set accessibility/screen_reader false
```

Comment: Really useful - thank you! Being able to see the format in the same style as on the official tutorials is lovely.

The docs confirm that this accessibility option governs the table display behaviour: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/enabling-accessibility-features 

I'm not sure *why* the accessibility/screen_reader is set to 'true' by default for us (maybe it defaults from the browser - I'm using Edge rather than Chrome).